# How to update a Data attribute defined with Maybe

Tags: haskell

I'm playing with Haskell using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cursor library. I have this data definition:

```
data TuidoState =
  TuidoState  { tuidoStateEntries :: Maybe (NonEmptyCursor Entry) }
```

And I have this function:

```
buildNewItem :: TuidoState -> TuidoState
buildNewItem s =
  let nextID = 10 -- TODO update here to function to return ID
      headerTitle = "Test new item"
      newEntry = Entry { entryHeader= Header { headerTitle= headerTitle }
                              , entryBody= Just (Body { bodyTitle= headerTitle })
                              , entryTags= [Tag {tagName= headerTitle}]
                              }
      actualEntries = (tuidoStateEntries s)
      ne = NE.nonEmpty [newEntry]
  in
    case actualEntries of
      Nothing ->
        s { tuidoStateEntries = Just(makeNonEmptyCursor ne)  }
      Just value -> s { tuidoStateEntries = Just(value) } -- possible here I will want to just add the new Entry to the existing list
```

But, I cannot understand the error:

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘NE.NonEmpty Entry’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe (NE.NonEmpty Entry)’
    • In the first argument of ‘makeNonEmptyCursor’, namely ‘ne’
      In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely ‘(makeNonEmptyCursor ne)’
      In the ‘tuidoStateEntries’ field of a record
    |
327 |         s { tuidoStateEntries = Just(makeNonEmptyCursor ne)  }
```

Could someone help me with it?

Comment: 1. `Just actualEntries` will never match the `Nothing` pattern, so that's dead code anyway. 2. You haven't shown us the definition of `tuidoStateEntries`, only `entries`. Perhaps you have mixed up two data structures with different field types but similar names in your head, or transcribed your code to SO incorrectly.

Comment: hi @DanielWagner , I update the code, I transcribed it to SO incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

`nonEmpty` takes an arbitrary list, and so cannot guarantee it returns a non-empty list. Instead, it returns a `Maybe (NonEmpty a)` to indicate that it may either return a nonempty list or cause an error.

Consider using `NonEmpty`'s constructor, `(:|)`, directly instead.

```
ne = newEntry NE.:| []
```